# How can I make the image zoom out to normal view?

Tags: html, css

I am making a gallery, but the images are zoomed in too close, I want the image to fit!

I tried some width and height adjustments, but it doesn't look right

Html code.

```
    <div class="bod">    
    <h1 class="header1">Gallery</h1>
        <div class="wrapper-gallery">
<div class="media">
<div class="layer">
    <p class="para">Student: RANDOM</p>
  </div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431818563807-927945852ab6?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=899&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" />
</div>
 <div class="media">
<div class="layer">
    <p class="para">Student: RANDOM</p>
  </div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431818563807-927945852ab6?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=899&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" />
</div>
   <div class="media">
<div class="layer">
    <p class="para">Student: RANDOM</p>
  </div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431818563807-927945852ab6?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1199&h=899&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt=""/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The css for the above!

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata|Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600');

.bod {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header1 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #151E3F;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.wrapper-gallery {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  > * {
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

.media {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
}

.layer {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 10px;
  height: 90%;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #151E3F;
  transition: all 0.9s ease;
  p {
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
    transform: scale(0.2)
  }
}

.para {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.media:hover .layer {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 95%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  p {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
  .bod {
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper-gallery {
    display: block;
    > * {
      margin: 10px;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

There are no errors, it just zooms in super close, and I cant get it to fit! Is there a way to make the image fit snugly?

Comment: When you say that it "zooms in super close", what exactly do you mean by that? Running your code above, it shows three images sitting next to each other. Both the left and right-most images are cut off at the side, and the header text is cut off as well. Do you want to constrain these so the whole text / carousel is visible?

Comment: if you take the code and run it with different images, random web images, it will zoom up real close.

Answer (score 0):

You are not dimensioning the `img`, so they are displaying with the original image size. Just add `width: 100%` and they should adjust to their parent element `width`.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Another solution, instead of using `img`, would be to use `background-image`:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('site.com/nice-image.png')</div>

.image {
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: I did specify it though:
```
.media {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@azametzin, **img** is not nested inside **layer**.

The error is in the CSS for .media. It's not valid, at least not in Chrome.

It should look like this:

```
.media {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.media img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention there are other CSS errors in there that need to be fixed as well. wrapper-gallery, for instance. Open Chrome, hit F12, then right-click and inspect elements on the page. You'll see a yellow ! triangle next to invalid CSS elements.

One final thought, this design doesn't work at all for mobile devices. I'm not sure if that's a problem for your intended audience.